# Best way to transform Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas, and am wondering about the best way to accomplish this data transformation. The method below works, but I have a feeling that it can be done more cleanly/efficiently.

I have Office information that can be in the form:

- "<building>/<office>"
- "<building>"
- <building number> (int)
- '' (empty string)
- None

I'd like to convert this into Building and Office columns.

Given the data:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({ "Office" : [ "Building Foo/10", "Building Only", None, 100, ""]})
df

    Office
0   Building Foo/10
1   Building Only
2   None
3   100
4
```

I can transform it via:

```
items = [ (str(row["Office"]) or '').rsplit('/', 1) for _, row in df.iterrows() ]
items = [ item if len(item) == 2 else (item[0] or None, None) for item in items ]

df["Building"], df["Office"] = zip(*items)
df

    Office  Building
0   10      Building Foo
1   None    Building Only
2   None    None
3   None    100
4   None    None
```

What is the best way to do this using pandas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: IMO your DataFrame is wrong. Each Office needs its own line in the frame. You know what a Series is? A DataFrame is a table of _n_ Series.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no *best* way to do this, but here's one that is good enough:

```
pd.DataFrame([(None,None) if not o else 
              (None,   o) if isinstance(o, int) else 
              tuple(o.split("/")) for o in df.Office],
             columns=("Building", "Office"))
#        Building Office
#0   Building Foo     10
#1  Building Only   None
#2           None   None
#3           None    100
#4           None   None
```

You can achieve the same result with `apply`. The latter approach preserves the row indexes:

```
df['Office'].apply(lambda x: 
                   pd.Series((None,None) if not x else 
                             (None,   x) if isinstance(x, int) else 
                             tuple(x.split("/"))))
#               0     1
#0   Building Foo    10
#1  Building Only   NaN
#2           None  None
#3           None   100
#4           None  None
```

(Remember to rename the columns).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [99]: df.Office = df.Office.astype(str)

In [100]: df[['Building','Office']] = \
              df.Office.str.replace(r'(\d+)', r'/\1').str.split(r'\/+', expand=True)

In [101]: df
Out[101]:
  Office       Building
0     10   Building Foo
1   None  Building Only
2   None           None
3    100
4   None
```